# image is displaying as icon in local notifications. how to display image as big picture style in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i am using local notifications plugin to display notification messages locally. when i tried to display notification along with image it is getting displayed as icon [image]

actually i need it to be look like

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: code is there is in plugin i am using the same just trying to pass image in same

Comment: If you are using this plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/local_notifications then this does not support what you are looking for

Comment: Can you please share which plugin you are using so that I can help you.

Comment: i am using pub.dartlang.org/packages/local_notifications above plugin only.. i have tried with flutter_local_notifications also. it too don't have big picture style mode

Comment: In Android you have to write custom UI to achieve the same. Here you have to write the android specific code and then using platform channel you can call this method.

Comment: i am new to both flutter and android. can you guide me how to achieve this?? any example or tutorial?

Comment: In that case, first study the platform channels from the flutter

Comment: @dhuma1981 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for someone like me, try check the flutter_local_notifications  example app. He already provide the example how to read from url and convert them to bitmap to show in local notification.